# howto define current date for an android sqlite db, in a contract?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Howto define current date (or datetime) in contract for android studio sqlite db?

I have searched internet without any luck. Perhaps here?

```
    public class ParkContract
{
        private  ParkContract() {}


        // define table (named general)
        public static final class RegisterEntry implements BaseColumns
        {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "general";

        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_CURRENTDATE = ????????;

        }


}
```

Comment: Why you are not using the easy way CURRENT_DATE? It's self commented code.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of the CURRENT_DATE  but Im not sure how the statement would be written in a contract? thanks

Comment: store in long time